# How can I have newly created files available on all servers immediately or is it possible to force request to be executed on a specific server?

Tags: php, file, filesystems

I have a web page A that is reading a file and, if the file does not exist yet, requests another page B of the same website,  through a socket connection, to create this file.

This is coded in PHP and the socket connection between those two pages is established with `stream_socket_client`.

The problem I am having is that it sometimes (most of the time it is ok) takes too long (it may take up to 1 minute in that case and I would need up to a few seconds max) for the file that was created in page B to be visible from page A:

- `file_exists` and `fopen` fail on page A but succeeds later on on page B (I did `clearstatcache()` on both page previously);
- I can also see that all the other that were previously created but the new one are present by doing a `scandir`;
- finally I can confirm the file was created before the time I try to read it from page A by doing a `filectime` on page B).

When the problem occurs, it seems that case page A and page B are running on different servers of the same website that is hosted in a shared hosting.

Do you know if:

- if it is normal that the files created on one server sometimes take so long to be visible from the other server, and if, in the case of host sharing plan, there would be any workaround?
- if it is possible to force the socket (I am using stream_socket_client) to be established to a specific server of the website (I would like page B to be executed on same server than page A)?
- any other idea of the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you are scrapping. Kindly provide more info about the site you are scrapping and your scrapping code. As for your question. 1. Yes, files created on one server can take time to sync on other servers, as it depends on syncing techniques between servers and their sync time cycle. 2. Yes, but you need ip of that server, even then the server should be setup to allow file access through ip.

Comment: No, I am not scrapping, both pages are from my same website. I don't think it helps to have more info about the site. Concerning the questions: 1. So maybe I should contact the shared web hosting administrator to get more info concerning those sync techniques and parameters. 2. I can get the ip address of the server I want to request; would you know then if it possible to  establish connection to that specific server with stream_socket_client and how? Thanks!